# Is there a substance that binds with the sodium in salt (NaCl) in solution so that the sodium can be removed (precipitated out, for example)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Is there a substance that binds with the sodium in salt $\ce{NaCl}$ in solution so that the sodium can be removed (precipitated out, for example)?
Could such a substance make salt water potable?

Comment: I think your question would benefit from a bit more specificity. In particular, what do you mean by "bind?" Do you want molecules that will chelate the ions while remaining soluble, or do you want something that will precipitate the ions out of solution?

Comment: The recent edit makes the question clear. Can something be added to salt water to precipitate out the sodium, leaving a filtrate that could then easily be made drinkable?

Answer (score 5):

$\ce{NaCl}$ itself does not exist as a compound in water. The dissolution of salt in water means that both the sodium cation and the chloride anion are separated from each other and are each surrounded by water molecules. Therefore, no compound can bind to NaCl in water because $\ce{NaCl}$ does not exist in water.

It is, however, possible that a compound "binds" with either sodium or chlorine. For example, by adding copper to the solution and performing a bit of more electrochemical magic (out of the scope of this answer), you can get the solid compound copper chloride ($\ce{CuCl}$).

Comment: All compounds of sodium are soluble in water, except $\ce{NaMg(UO2)2(CH3COO)9·6H2O}$. So sodium ions can be recognized in solution by preparing a solution containing magnesium acetate and uranyl acetate. Adding a solution containing some $\ce(Na^+} ions produces a crystalline yellow precipitate. The trouble is that uranium is radioactive, and cannot be used any more in the lab. The best method to determine sodium in a solution is to pulverize the solution in the flame, and analyze the flame spectrum. A yellow line (or double line) shows that the solution contains sodium

Comment: Ah, @Maurice, you left out cryolite! ;-)

Comment: @Maurice sodium silicates are extremely insoluble in water. NaAlSi2O6, or NaAl3Si3O8 are two examples.

Comment: Yes, cryolithe and silicates are insoluble into water. But they cannot be used for detecting sodium in water. Because no aqueous solution exist that can be added to a sodium solution so as to show that this solution contains sodium, and makes a precipitate of silicate or cryolithe.

Comment: @Maurice ever heard of TEOS? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetraethyl_orthosilicate

Comment: @Gimelist. Tetraethyl orthosilicate is decomposed by water, producing some insoluble deposit of silica. So it is useless for analyzing sodium (or any other ion) in water solutions.